# Are AES-NI crypto instructions used by my Tor (relay) server?

Tags: configuration, relays, speed, performance, fast-relays

I have a server with Linux Debian 8.4, running a relay.

I read that [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) could improve the performance of my relay. Or at least, less stress the CPU by crypto operations.

Proof of [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) detected by the system:

```
$ grep aes /proc/cpuinfo > /dev/null; echo $?
```

with the result of **`0`**, which means my CPU **does** support it.

---

I read that it depends on OpenSSL package version, so:

```
$ apt-cache policy openssl

openssl:  
Installed: 1.0.1k-3+deb8u5  
Candidate: 1.0.1k-3+deb8u5  
Version table:  
*** 1.0.1k-3+deb8u5 0  
      500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages  
      100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Tor version is:

```
$ tor --version

Tor version 0.2.7.6 (git-605ae665009853bd).
```

---

How do I ensure or check if Tor actually uses [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) CPU instructions directly or indirectly?

Comment: Given the packages and version numbers involved, Tor is pretty definitely using AES-NI, but i'm not sure how to _prove_ it...

Comment: I wasn't mistaken. `HardwareAccel` is for a different type of feature.

Comment: `HardwareAccel` is for dynamically loading engines. OpenSSL >= 1.0.1 enables AES-NI **by default** and does not need an engine.

Comment: By eyeballing the source code: [here we actually use HardwareAccel](https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/13e93bdfd5a3bc8349723a0e3a9e05f2dd300f99/src/app/main/main.c#L666), calling [here](https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/2f683465d4b666c5d8f84fb3b234ad539d8511cd/src/lib/crypt_ops/crypto_init.c#L81) and comes down to [here](https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/2f683465d4b666c5d8f84fb3b234ad539d8511cd/src/lib/crypt_ops/crypto_openssl_mgt.c#L335), which calls `crypto_openssl_init_engines` if `useAccel > 0` (which is `HardwareAccel == 1` if I am correct) and does nothing if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to mention, I am running my relay from home, so I have physical access to it, but if you don't, always be prepared for the worst - have a backup of your relay keys, and a backup of your configuration before actually doing any big changes. This answer might contain changes that could lead to your relay operation disruption.

---

## Updated 2019-Mar-07

---

### In the recent [Tor Relay Guide](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorRelayGuide#CPU) I've found

> It is recommended to use CPUs with [AESNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) support (that will improve performance and allow for up to about ~400-450 Mbps in each direction on a single tor instance on modern CPUs). If the file `/proc/cpuinfo` contains the word `aes` your CPU has support for [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set).

---

### Additional info found on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tor#Tor_configuration)

> If `# cat /proc/cpuinfo` returns that your CPU supports AES instructions and `# lsmod` returns that the module is loaded, you can specify `HardwareAccel 1` which tries "*to use built-in (static) crypto hardware acceleration when available*", see http://www.torservers.net/wiki/setup/server#aes-ni_crypto_acceleration

---

### Checking your setup: HW + OS

1. Find, find if your **CPU supports [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set)**, with:

   ```
   $ grep aes /proc/cpuinfo > /dev/null; echo $?
   ```

   where **`0`** means your CPU **does** support it; and **`1`** means it **does not**.
2. Second, find if the **module for [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) is loaded**, with:

   ```
   $ lsmod | grep -i aes

   aesni_intel           200704  1
   aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
   crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
   cryptd                 28672  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
   glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
   ```

---

### Checking your setup: Software

1. OpenSSL must be version 1.0.1 or above, please check yours, with:

   ```
   $ openssl version
   ```

   Example output:

   ```
   OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018
   ```
2. Tor must be version > 0.2.2 ([unofficial claim](https://tor-talk.torproject.narkive.com/UW07zYDr/no-subject#post84), [changelog](https://github.com/evoskuil/tor/blob/master/ChangeLog#L924)), please check yours, with:

   ```
   $ tor --version
   ```

   Example output:

   ```
   Tor version 0.3.5.8.
   ```

I recommend you stay up-to-date in all circumstances.

---

Here I can actually answer my question: Yes, indeed, if you fulfill the requirements above, Tor performance can be greatly improved by enabling [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) instructions use. Please follow the below chapter in order to enable [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) use.

---

### Enabling the use of [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) instructions

Settings option: `HardwareAccel` which can be `0` or `1` ([link to wiki](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#HardwareAccel)).

> **If non-zero**, try to **use** built-in (static) **crypto hardware acceleration when available**. Can not be changed while tor is running. (**Default: 0**)

So, stop your relay with:

```
# systemctl stop tor.service
```

Add to Tor global settings file:

```
/etc/tor/torrc
```

This line, and make sure it is not there yet, with your favorite text editor:

```
HardwareAccel 1
```

Finally, you can start your Tor relay / bridge, with:

```
# systemctl start tor.service
```

You are done now. Either your relay / bridge will be faster, or the CPU will not be stressed as much.

---

### VPS (Virtual Private Server) without the `aes` flag passed workaround

There is also a way to force OpenSSL [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) usage on a VPS without the `aes` CPU flag passthrough for Tor. To do so, I would proceed like this:

1. Run *normal* OpenSSL benchmark, for example:

   ```
   $ openssl speed -elapsed -evp aes-128-gcm
   ```
2. Run it with a special flag, and simply check if it is multiple times faster:

   ```
   $ OPENSSL_ia32cap="+0x200000200000000" openssl speed -elapsed -evp aes-128-gcm
   ```

If it was way faster in your case, then it proves your VPS provider does not allow passing the `aes` CPU flag into your Virtual Machine.

---

You can do the following, which **you will have to repeat with each Tor upgrade**:

1. Stop Tor service, and edit the following file with your favorite text editor:

   ```
   /etc/init.d/tor
   ```
2. Right after the first line, which stands:

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   ```

   Add this line and start the Tor service again.

   ```
   export OPENSSL_ia32cap="+0x200000200000000"
   ```

More detailed info can be found [here](https://romanrm.net/force-enable-openssl-aes-ni-usage), I have re-written the most important parts only, so you should read it too.

Not only your relay / bridge might be faster, your VPS provider will actually be happy for you to use less of the CPU time!

Comment: I’m pretty sure the “HardwareAccel” flag doesn’t enable AES-NI (it’s used for something else), but I’ll try to remember to look into this later.

Answer (score 2):

It depends:

https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/common/aes.c#n44

(Link has been removed, I've been unable to find it in the archive, maybe someone else will.)

on if the OpenSSL it was built against supports it.

---

As you're using OpenSSL 1.0.1 it should be in use, see [torservers documentation](https://www.torservers.net/wiki/setup/server#aes-ni_crypto_acceleration).

Actually directly confirming that OpenSSL is using [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) seems like a [trickier subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284119/how-can-i-check-if-openssl-is-support-use-the-intel-aes-ni).